# User: 1000-user#1000

Tags: community

My hard disk (boot sector) is blown but the partition with my data in is good.

When I loasd up Ubuntu 13:05 LiveDisk, and move to my data partition, I notice that I have no access to the files and the permissions say that the files are owned by

User: 1000-user#1000

OK, I found "Ubuntu Hardware Partitions: How to Set Ownership of Drive or Partition (Internal & External Hard Disks)" Followed the instructions very carefully but the system would not recognise 1000-user#1000 - it may have been the hash sign it doesn't like?

Can anyone shed some light on this as I would like to get my data back before dumping the hard drive.

If it is any help. I have moved the damaged disk to bay 1 from Bay 0 and have a new drive in Bay 0 (which won't at present load Ubuntu - but I'm not worried about that at present.

Answer (score 0):

If you have or can create a LiveCD/USB, boot from that and use nautilus to copy files to a safe backup drive.

This should help save any valuable data.

Answer (score 0):

User 1000 is the first user you created on ubuntu (Your Useraccount). It is not available in Live Environment.

You should be able to open the hardrive as root with no problems (except you encrypted your home partition).

Open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), open nautilus as root (sudo nautilus), then open your mounted partition.

Or if you work with Terminal only change to root with "su -i" and to your task, afterwards "exit" to exit the root modus.

Good Luck.